# Is program count everything right with fork and processes?

Tags: c, fork

I just need to know if i'm right. With this forks() before the switch in the loop that will gonna be made one time, the number of processes should be 5 right? And if i'm gonna add more forks() this number gonna increase to 9,17,etc.? And i'm courius in this case how this processes are creating new ones, is the next forks() only creating new processes from childs or from parent too because i can't draw it properly because i dont know how to check processes creating new ones.
Maybe it is obvious question but i think i miss something and i want to make sure that i understand it good.

Thanks!

[Is it gonna look like this? (i made a draw)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vgOoX.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>

void processTree()
{
    pid_t pid_t = getpid();
    int tmp = pid_t;
    printf("PID : %d\n",pid_t);
    char buffer [128];

    for(int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
    {
        int pid_child;
        fork();
        fork(); //if i am gonna add more fork there will be 9,17,etc processes?
        switch(pid_child = fork())
        {
        case -1:
            exit(-1);
        case 0:
            pid_t = pid_child;
            
            
            printf("UID: %d, GID: %d, PID: %d, PPID: %d\n", getuid(), getgid(), getpid(), getppid()); fflush(stdout);
            break;
        
        }
    

 }

int main()
{
    processTree();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do not tag C++ for C questions.

Comment: Sorry, my bad...

Comment: the posted code does not compile!   Please post code that compiles

Comment: It is compiling for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `for` loop iterates once, so it's irrelevant. The show starts with one process, the one that's executing `main()`, which does a

```
fork();
```

There are now two processes. Each one of the two processes does a

```
fork();
```

There are now four processes. Each one of those four processes does a

```
switch(pid_child = fork())
```

There are now eight processes.

Nothing else that the shown program did before, or did after all the `fork()` is material, with respect to the total number of processes in the end.

Grand total: eight processes.

Comment: Oh, i understand now i guess... I didnt have printing the processes after 2 forks() in for loop and i think that blow my mind what i'm doing wrong. So if am gonna add another fork() this will be 16 processes. But i have question in mind what's gonna happen we will add fork() in switch case(0)? Because my program printing 12 processes. And i dont know why...

Comment: You'll have to work out, with paper and pen, how many processes will reach that `fork()`. Then, add the exact same amount to the pot.

Comment: Hm, so in the case when 2 forks() are before switch and one fork is in case 0 we will have 16 processes? Because 8 processes reach that fork() in case 0?

Comment: No we won't, because there won't be 8 processes that reach case 0.

Comment: Why is that? We ignoring switch(pid_child = fork())? Or I'm missing something...

Comment: What you're missing is that of the 8 processes that leave that `fork()` not all of them reach case 0. What does your technical reference for the `fork()` system call say about the return value from it? In any case, you should be able to figure out the answer simply by adding some additional print statement that show each pid and what it's return value from `fork()` is.

Comment: So before fork() in case 0 there will be 4 processes... so grand total will be 8 too?

Comment: Does this really make sense to you: as is, with the shown code, there are eight processes. An additional change is made that results in some of those processes forking again. And you still think there's going to be eight processes, in total? Are you aware that you're able to figure this out in ten seconds simply by adding an addition statement that prints "Hello world", that every process ends up executing, and then simply counting how many times this appears?

Comment: It is printing 12 times of end total. Before fork in case 0 there is lets say 4 hello worlds;
case 0:
            printf("hello world\n");
            fork();
            break;
And after all there is 12 processes how can fork make 4 processes to 12? We just like adding this 8 made processes in the case 0 to the 4 processes before switch and that is total of 12? If yes why is that?

Comment: You forgot the 8 processes that already existed at that point, in the shown code. Putting a `fork()` in case 0 doesn't make the three previous forks, that resulted in 8 processes do absolutely nothing.